# Moving Imperative to Declarative- character limitations

Tags: javascript

One module in my app pulls records from a mongodb and prints out the fields for the user to see.  The fields are displayed in a particular order.  The order is stored in an array.  The mongodb document (`pers`) may not have all of the fields possible filled out.  Anyway, here is an example of my original code.  It works.  I want to move onto something better.  I will explain as I go.

```
const keys = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape']

const pers = {
    banana: 'word',
    orange: 'e t',
    apple: 'scrabble',
}
let entries = []
let entry = ''

keys.forEach(key => {
    if (pers[key]) entries.push(pers[key])
})

for (let i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    if ((entries.length + entries[i].length < 10) entry += '\n' + entries[i]
    else {
        console.log(entry) //message.send in my app
        entry = entries[i]
    }
}
console.log(entry)
```

So in my app, the message that is sent cannot be longer than 2000 characters.  I am using 10 characters for the example here in the post.  And I do not want them split up in the middle either.  So for instance 'word' + 'e t' is the maximum I can concatenate together.  If I try to add 'scrabble' to it, the total length will be over 10 characters in length.  So I want to send 'word e t' to the console and then start the variable `entry` over.  I also do not want to send 'word' and then 'e' and then 't' and then 'scrabble'.  Like I said before, my existing code works.  I just want to try and be clear on my intent.

Moving forward...  Below is my second iteration of the code.  I'm trying to move away from imperative statements to declarative.  So I replaced the `forEach` block.  This also works great.

```
const keys = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape']

const pers = {
    banana: 'word',
    orange: 'e t',
    apple: 'scrabble',
}
let entry = ''

const entries = keys.filter(key => pers.hasOwnProperty(key)).map(key => pers[key])

for (let i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    if ((entries.length + entries[i].length < 10) entry += '\n' + entries[i]
    else {
        console.log(entry)
        entry = entries[i]
    }
}
console.log(entry)
```

The console output for both of these is:

```
word
e t
scrabble
```

That is exactly what I wanted.  Now I really want to move away from that `for` block if possible.  Surely there is a way to add another chain to my declarative statement to take care of that portion?  I could possibly see a way of doing it if I didn't have the character limitation.

Anyway, if I have been unclear in any of my description or intent, please let me know and I will do my best to clarify.

Thanks!!

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: Yes I was attempting to write something with reduce. Any help in that direction would be great!

Comment: Also not sure why this post got downvoted on less than 15 minutes. An explanation why would be helpful.

Comment: i think your post got downvoted because there's no problem in it and it's working fine, and should be posted in https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead for improvement.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and recommendation Taki. I will know for future questions! :)

Comment: @Bergi typo. Late at night when I posted. Good catch. I'll correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the find.  Totally didn't notice that when I read back over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.reduce` like this. Your original code had a syntax error, so I'm assuming that was just a typo and not something important.

While that's functionally identical to your current code, it's still pretty convoluted. If I were you, I'd create an array of `entryStrs` while iterating, and then `console.log` them all later, like this:

```js
const keys = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape']
const pers = {
  banana: 'word',
  orange: 'e t',
  apple: 'scrabble',
}

const { currentMessage, messages } = keys
  .filter(key => pers.hasOwnProperty(key))
  .map(key => pers[key])
  .reduce(({ currentMessage = '', messages = [] }, entry, i, entries) => {
    if (entries.length + entry.length < 10) {
      currentMessage += currentMessage
        ? ('\n' + entry)
        : entry;
    } else {
      messages.push(currentMessage)
      currentMessage = entry;
    }
    return { currentMessage, messages };
  }, {});
const allMessages = [...messages, currentMessage];
console.log(allMessages.join('\n-----\n-----\n'));
```

Comment: I'd thought about changing it to an array and passing that to console.log as an improvement. Thank you for that. I'll give your reduce suggestion a whirl tomorrow and let you know how it went. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I would consider reducing to another array of chunks to avoid the stray logs? `.reduce(...).forEach(message.send)`

Comment: There is a rate limitation on message.send. I try to send as many of the entries into one message that I can so that the user doesn't experience the limitation lag. Doing it with my original code, I've only had it broken down to two message.send calls thankfully. Keeping it under 5 would be a requirement and there are 25 or so entries stored in a doc.

Comment: I certainly like where both of you are going with this answer. This is what I was looking for. I was hoping to avoid the if else block, but I assumed it wouldn't be entirely possible.

Comment: I will hopefully take the suggestions from both of you tomorrow and make it turn the array of chunks as you called it. I like that much better than appending a string. While CertainPerformance gave me a great answer and leaving my functionality fully in tact, you both suggested using the array instead. I was very much hoping for that anyway. I will hopefully have time tomorrow to write it all out and get back to you.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to reduce it down into an array of entries as @CertainPerformance and @thgaskell described.  Returning `['word\e t','scrabble']` would be perfect.  I hate to bug you guys any more.  You have been such great help already.

Comment: See edit. I also fixed it so that the initial message wouldn't create an unnecessary `\n` at the top. Remember to upvote/Accept answers if they're helpful to you.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I absolutely will!  I will have time for another iteration on the code here in about an hour.  Thank you again for your extra time and attention!

Comment: This is certainly more code than my original. lol. I wonder if I'm doing the right thing by making this switch. However, I will say that I'm not the type to copy and paste. I will breakdown this answer and use it as a learning experience. I will also apply this to my live code. What are your thoughts on me making the move from my code to this? Also, how much of a pain/challenge was this for you? :D Thanks again!

Comment: My snippet is an example of (mostly) functional programming, which is generally easier to read, reason about, and debug later, compared to an imperative style. While functional is sometimes longer, the *intent* is clearer. As ecmabot says: Loops fail to clearly signal the intention of your code, and as such should be avoided whenever possible (prefer higher-order functions, such as .map, .reduce, .filter, ...). See also: http://qr.ae/RNMEGA and https://gist.github.com/robotlolita/7643014 The rest is just a result of the natural use of `.reduce`, which was second nature to me.

Comment: It's great work.  I also think I have returned multiple variables at once like you did with `{ currentMessage, messages }` only once.  I'm also not using the spread operator very often.  This will give me a bit to work on.  It's hard for me to get used to working more with higher order functions instead of loops.  I started programming in BASIC over 30 years ago.  I've mostly used C and PHP in the days since.  Functional programming isn't second nature to me yet.  Thank you again for the work and for the learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

since in the `for` block you have to iterate and change an external variable and not changing anything in the array itself, you can use [Conditional (tenary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and replace [for with forEach()](https://thejsguy.com/2016/07/30/javascript-for-loop-vs-array-foreach.html)

```js
const keys = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'grape']

const pers = {
  banana: 'word',
  orange: 'e t',
  apple: 'scrabble',
}

let entry = ''

const entries = keys.filter(key => pers.hasOwnProperty(key)).map(key => pers[key])

entries.forEach(e => {
  entries.length + e.length < 10 ? entry += '\n' + e : (console.log(entry), entry = e)
});

console.log(entry)
```